# StackDriver in PHP / How to setup the LoggingClient for Google AppEngine PHP/Flex

Tags: php, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm switching to the Google LoggingClient to log to StackDriver.

It's working, I've managed to switch the "resource->type" from global to gae_app (since my PHP App is running in Google App Engine Flex), but in the label section, I can't set the the module_id and version_id.

Ideally, I would see the GAE logs with the PHP logs of my application.

## The code

In SlimFramework dependency, I've setup the logger as follow :

```
/**
 * @property PsrLogger    $logger
 * @param \Slim\Container $c
 * @return PsrLogger
 */
$container['logger'] = function (\Slim\Container $c)
{
  $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];

  $logger = LoggingClient::psrBatchLogger(
    $settings['name'], [
    'resource'=>[
      'type'=>'gae_app'
    ],
    'labels'  =>['module_id=>'default', 'version_id'=>'XXXXX']
    ]);


  return $logger;
};
```

## What I'm currently getting:

```
resource: {
 labels: {
  module_id:  ""    
  project_id:  "redcrossquest-fr-dev"    
  version_id:  ""    
 }
 type:  "gae_app"   
}
```

Ideally, I would like to fill the module_id & version_id with the values from GoogleAppEngine instance.